# How would i represent CC Practitioners in FHIR Bundle

Tags: hl7-fhir

I have a FHIR Bundle with requisition report that needs to go to multiple Practitioners. How would i represent this, would it be via references in a MessageHeader or...?

Comment: Are you interested in the message routing piece, or the report's declaration of who it's for?

Comment: Thanks - i have a use case for both routing and declaration.

Answer (score 0):

In the MessageHeader itself, we're a bit unclear on the meaning of multiple destinations.  It might be for fan-out routing where the message is pushed to an initial recipient, which then sends to multiple places.  Alternatively, it might tell the destination who else received the message (though at the 'routing' level, this is generally not useful information, so I'd presume only the first is intended).

The more useful level (the level surfaced at a business level and retained after delivery) for a cc is on the DiagnosticReport itself.  Surprisingly, there's no standard element or extension for defining that.  You could certainly define your own, but it might be worth submitting a change request and soliciting a standard extension for that purpose - to indicate who all intended recipients of the report are.

Comment: Thanks Lloyd, much appreciated. Correct about the MessageHeadr, would be for fan-out. 
We also have a se case for the DocRef as well, i'll look at submitting a change request for this.  Thanks again

Comment: I'm formulating a short and long term strategy for referencing the Providers destination. Most Practitioners in our use case are receiving forms via Fax which doesn't conform to destination.endpoint. Long term we would build out references to different Practitioners to gather their communication info.  However, I've also seen that we could possibly just use the Organization resource with an organization.type of "prov". Would it make sense to just reference Organization resources from MessageHeader versus creating Practioners and associated Organization (long term would have both)?